# How to count database rows?

Tags: python, sqlite

hey i need some help i'm making a order system and i need help

here is what i need it to: i need it to read value in the rows so if the order is complete then value 2 and print out that the order is complete if the order is still active then the value should be 1 and it prints out the order is still active

Long story short i need help retrieving the number and determining if the order is a active order or its complete

here is what i have

```
sqx = "SELECT Customer_Status FROM Customer WHERE Username = 'Test' AND order_Status ='1'"                                            
cursor.execute(sqx)                                                                                                                   
result = cursor.fetchall()                                                                                                            
if result == '2':                                                                                                                    
    print('Order is complete')                                                                                                        
else:                                                                                                                                 
    print('order is active')
```

Comment: `result = cursor.fetchall()  ` returns a list of tuples. `result == '2'` will be always False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At it's core, you want to use fetchone() and pull out the tuple.  Also, you really should start using parameter substitution to prevent any security issues from appearing in the future.

```python
# It's always a good ide to use parameter substitution to prevent 
# security issues.  There aren't any here, but this is generally 
# good practice
sqx = "SELECT Customer_Status FROM Customer WHERE Username = ? AND order_Status = ?"
cursor.execute(sqx, ('Test', '1'))

# We only want to look at one row, so use fetchone instead of 
# fetchall. And in that row, go ahead and pull out the first 
# value out of the tuple that's returned
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result is None:
    # Either the user or order status is invalid
    print("No match for query")
else:
    result = result[0]

    # And note here:  Is the database storing '1' and '2' as strings instead of integers?
    # If it is, this is fine, but if this field is an integer, 
    # use "result == 2" instead of "result == '2'"
    if result == '2':
        print('Order is complete')
    else:
        print('order is active')
```

Comment: so i tryed your code and i get this error any fix? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Updated the code to deal with the "no results" case.  I'd expect either the username or order_status is wrong (are you really storing the order_status and customer_status as strings?)

Comment: Okay, then use integers `1` and `2` instead of `'1'` and `'2'`